# node.js csv file not downloading

Tags: json, node.js, csv, express

I am trying to download a csv file. I found a few tutorials and I'm following this example:

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');

router.get('/api/exportmetric', function(req, res) {
    console.log('export metric hit');
    var fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age'];
    var people = [
      {
        "first_name": "George",
        "last_name": "Lopez",
        "age": "31"
      }, {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "age": "15"
      }, {
        "first_name": "Jenna",
        "last_name": "Grassley",
        "age": "44"
      }
    ];

    json2csv({ data: people, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
      res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testing.csv');
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
      console.log(csv)
      res.status(200).send(csv);
    });
});
```

If I check my network console tab, i get a `200` status; however, the file does not show up in my `downloads` folder.

Can someone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: I tried in Iron (Chromium), IE11 and Firefox and it works as expected.

Comment: does the file download & show up in your downloads folder? or do you just get the csv response?

Comment: Iron dowloads it directly to the Downloads folder and IE/Firefox ask me if I want to open or download the file.

Comment: hmm weird.. it doesn't do that for me. I tried on chrome, firefox, safari (i'm on a mac)